# Google SpeechClient efficiency for medical terminology

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying build something that requires a doctor or a medical scribe to dictate the findings. Using Google SpeechClient in GCP python sdk to recognise the audio and convert into text. But it roughly has an error rate of 15~20%.

For eg: "Byrd Respirator" is being recognised as "Bird Respirator". "Cheyne–Stokes respiration" is being recognised as "Shane Stokes respiration".

I've tried this in many possible utterrances. Is there any other provision or some other library add-on in order to improve its accuracy ?

Answer (score 1):

"Byrd Respirator" and "Bird Respirator" sound identical. I would recommend doing a replace in your code for this scenario.

For obscure words/phrases, you can add phrases as hints: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/context-strength

Comment: Well, that's good start by adding some medical vocabulary into the context. Other approach would be use some NLP techniques to post process the response.
Thanks @Brendan